# Need to read massive JSON file

Tags: java, json, groovy

I need to read a massive JSON (10+ G) file and then persist this to a Mongo instance.
If I use JSONSlurper and parse in one go it would put big pressure on the heap.

Is there any way I can stream in the JSON file and then persist the objects in the file whilst streaming the JSON?

Sort of analogy would be SAX or StAX in XML?

Thanks

Comment: [Java API for JSON Processing -JSR 353](https://jsonp.java.net) offers good streaming features. See section [19.4 Using the Streaming API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp004.htm#BABDBHIA).

Comment: Jackson can read JSON in a streaming fashion... http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi